# Include react-vr in react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-360

I would like to know if it's possible to integrate a react vr tour inside an Android and/or iOS app developed with react native. If so, how can I do it?

This is just an idea but I haven't found a real solution on-line.

Thanks for your attention.

(I'm  Italian. Excuse me if you do not understand my English)

Comment: Very few react libraries that output UIs work on react native.  You would need to find one that explicitly supports it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually mix the usage of these two libraries. react-vr depends on react-native but has a totally different runtime. One possible solution is having a web view in react-native and displaying the react-vr content inside.